# Gstreamer applying perspective element properties

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I would like to make use of the Gstreamer perspective element:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/geometrictransform/perspective.html?gi-language=c

I just don't know exactly how to apply the matrix property or what format it should be expecting. I see that it needs a GValueArray to be applied to the element but what is the best way of doing this? What method is needed to apply the matrix? Is it possible to do this with gst-launch as well?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you cannot do it from command line with the current version of gstreamer.

```
static gboolean gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array (GValue * dest, const gchar * s)
{
  g_warning ("gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented");
}
```

https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/gst/gstvalue.c

You can pass a array to some other elements (such as audioconvert) like this
matrix="<<1.0, 0.0, 0.0>, <0.0, 1.0, 0.0>, <0.0, 0.0, 1.0>>"

But perspective does not allow this, because property type is different (GValueArray instead of GstValueArray)

Your best bet is to write an application, and create a GValueArray manually using C functions.

Failing that you could report a bug.

Comment: Hi. Have just tried that and it doesn't look to work. I'm getting WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "matrix" in element "perspective0" to "<<1.0, 0.0, 0.0>, <0.0, 1.0, 0.0>, <0.0, 0.0, 1.0>>".

I've also tried to escape the characters in my shell and get the same result.

Comment: You are right. It may be impossible from command line. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Sure. I had a feeling I would have to resort to using C to pass in the array. Will try this out.